# How does this regular expression work?

Tags: c#, regex

```
string line = @"George\t15\tStudent\tAddress\tB:\temp\profilepic.png";

string[] results = Regex.Split( line, @"(?<![a-zA-Z]:)\\t" )
```

it produces this list:

```
George
15
Student
Address
B:\temp\profilepic.png
```

But I can not understand how it works, particularly I can't find information about the "<" operator.

Comment: You are saying that you couldn't find any information about regex?? I think you haven't search enough..

Comment: @Dor cohen I have not said that

Comment: [Zero-Width Negative Lookbehind Assertions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bs2twtah.aspx#zerowidth_negative_lookbehind_assertion)

Comment: @L.B. Maybe, you are right, I thought was better to start another question

Comment: @Blau Your input string does not make sense. At all points, `\t` seems to mean a TAB character, except in the `\temp` case.

Comment: @Tomalak I know but is not mine, I only am interested in the regex... see first comment

Comment: @L.B. I think you are wrong with me...there is no classmate...

Comment: @L.B. I tried to give an answer to that question, (I did but I deleted because regex answer is much better), and now I only want learn about it...

Comment: @Blau, sorry.... It would be good if you had given a reference to that question :(

Comment: It could be just that this OP came to know about a particular question on SO and now he needs to know how does it work. No suspicion pls :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<` is not itself an operator in this case.  It's a part of the  `(?<!)` construct, which performs [negative lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).  Negative lookbehind can be a tricky concept and I personally think it falls into the category of "advanced regex."

`(?<!` begins the group and `)` closes it.

Answer (score 3):

`?<!` is a negative lookbehind assertion. This expression translates to "Find a `\t` character that is not immediately preceded by a letter and a colon together".

Comment: `\t` is not a `TAB` character, it's a sequence of two characters - `'\'` and `'t'`. The slash in regexp string is escaped once, and the string itself is prefixed with `@`, so regexp engine sees it as `\\t`.

Comment: Whoops... force of habit. Thanks!